# Spring Social: Get User (LinkedIn, Facebook) Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring, spring.net

I am using Spring Social to connect to LinkedIn and Facebook. I downloaded the source code from this link:

[Github Spring Social LinkedIn Examples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-linkedin)

In this project, I am running “Spring.MvcQuickStart” under examples [directory](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-linkedin/tree/master/examples/Spring.MvcQuickStart). It works pretty well but I don't know how to get the user’s email. I need to know how can I get the user’s email in the controller given at this [link](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-linkedin/blob/master/examples/Spring.MvcQuickStart/Spring.MvcQuickStart/Controllers/LinkedInController.cs).
I've added scope parameters like this:

```
parameters.Add("scope", "r_emailaddress r_fullprofile");
```

I can get the full profile of the user like this:

```
LinkedInFullProfile profile = linkedInClient.ProfileOperations.GetUserFullProfil eAsync().Result;
```

But the full profile does not contain user email (the email the user provided in his LinkedIn profile). I've no idea how to get the user's email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual implemtation does not read email attribute, but you can get it using classic REST operations:

```
JsonValue jsonResult = linkedIn.RestOperations.GetForObjectAsync<JsonValue>("people/{~}:(email-address)?format=json").Result;
```

Comment: Thanks. What about getting Twitter followers? I tried to do like this `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<CursoredList<TwitterProfile>> followers = twitterClient.FriendOperations.GetFollowersAsync();` but it returns nothing. I think Twitter API is different and there is nothing like scope parameters if I am not wrong. Please correct me if I've to add some scope parameter to get the followers list (ids and names)

Comment: Also, please help me how can I send direct message to any follower on Twitter?

Comment: 1 more thing. How to send HTML in LinkedIn Message? Supported by Spring Social API or not?

Comment: I've check the documentation on Spring Social website as well for FriendOperations at this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html) but the methods mentioned in documentation are not available to me in the API example uploaded by you on Github

Comment: There is actually 2 versions of the Twitter REST API: v1.0 (dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1) and v1.1 (dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

Comment: Spring.Social.Twitter 1.0.x works on REST API v1 and Spring.Social.Twitter 2.0 M1 works on REST API v1.1